# Linear Programming: Purely linear formulation (LP) for the expression "if x > 0; y =0 / if y > 0; x=0" without binary variables

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem which often occurs in energy system modelling (modelling of storages) where charging of a storage system is not allowed to when it is discharging and vice versa.

Let `x` and `y` be continous positive decision variables that represent the charging/discharging power of the storage unit. Now I am trying to express the following logic in equations or inequalities:

```
if x > 0:
    y = 0
if y > 0:
    x = 0
```

I know this can be realized with binary variables via the following equations if `b` is a binary variable and `x_ub` and `y_ub` represent the respective upper bound of the variables:

```
x <= b * x_ub
y <= (1-b) * y_ub
```

This results in a mixed-integer linear programm (MILP) and of course induces all the properties of a MILP which lay in higher runtimes, other interpretations of the solution, ...

Another way to get a pure LP formulation is to work with (very low) costs that are attached to `x` and `y` so that only one of both variables is set to a positive value. But this also affects my objective, has other disadvantages as is is somewhat of a hotfix.

So here's my question: Is there any way to express the logic above (if/else) in a purely linear program (LP)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get your 2nd approach and i'm pessimistic about this one. The only approach which comes to mind except for using MIP: use **one variable where positive values correspond to charging, negative values correspond to discharging (or vice versa)**. This of course has some effects on your modelling and might also kill convexity in some cases depending on what's going on in the rest of the model. (In my cases, convexity was never a problem and it was proven by the modelling-framework).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "I don't get your 2nd approach and i'm pessimistic about this one" (specifically related to energy system modelling): if no costs are assigned the usage of variables is indifferent in terms of the objective. Thereby assigning very low costs induces the desired behaviour and charging/discharging only takes place when it's beneficial in terms of the overall system costs.

Comment: Your "one variable solution" would be an option. But I have to see if I can implement it in the existing framework. Thanks!

Comment: My gut feeling is the a pure LP formulation is not possible. BTW: the constraints is equivalent to x*y = 0

Comment: Nice to see an expert (connected to Mosek?) giving his feeling. I might add, that when i used the one-var approach within cvxpy/cvxopt (on my simple problem), the framework might transform the final formulation to something which is convex, but not an LP. I did not check it, because it was not important for me (convex = polynomially solvable; often efficient except for some troublesome SDP-formulations), but it's possible, that the final problem was solved as SOCP instead of LP (which the open-source solver ECOS can solve; but also all of the commercial ones like Gurobi, CPLEX and Mosek).